# Twig ternary operator, if-then in WordPress with Timber

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

Sometimes my posts have {{post.content}} and sometime they don't - I would like to write this statement in in shorthand twig to display the posts content if it there otherwise it would do nothing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not sure if its this ```{{ post.content ? 'yes' : 'no' }}``` or if its this  ```{{ post.content ? 'yes' : '' }}``` or ```{{ post.content ? }}```

Answer (score 0):

Just putting in `{{ post.content }}` seems to work just fine, but not sure if its exactly proper?